# Hadoop log4j cannot find KafkaLog4JAppender.class

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, log4j, apache-kafka

I added KafkaLog4JAppender functionality to my MR job.
locally the job is running and sending the formatted logs into my Kafka cluster.

when I try to run it from the yarn server, using:

```
jar [jar-name].jar [DriverClass].class [job-params] -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml -libjars
```

I get the following expception:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
```

the KafkaLog4JAppender class is in the path. 
running

```
jar tvf [my-jar].jar | grep KafkaLog4J
```

finds the class

I'm kinda lost and would appreciate any helpfull input

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If it works in local mode and not working in Yarn/distributed mode, then it could be problem of jar not being distributed properly. YOu might want to check [Using third part jars and files in your MapReduce application(Distributed cache)](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-third-part-jars-and-files-in-your.html) for details on how to distribute your jar containing KafkaLog4jAppender.class

Comment: I actually tried both options and didn't work, any reason you know for -libjars to not work? I suspect that hadoop classpath somehow overrides this